# Seeking Boston shapefile 1630?

Tags: shapefile, united-states

I found this map on Reddit and was curious if anyone knows how it was made.

https://www.reddit.com/r/boston/comments/2xu9ix/modern_map_of_boston_compared_to_original_1630/

I think I could make it if I had a shapefile of the 1630 map.

Does anyone know how I could get that?

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Will do. Thanks @PolyGeo

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15320/boston-shapefile-1630

Comment: We highly encourage spatial opendata questions at GIS SE. There is significant support within the community for including spatial opendata questions at GIS SE: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4156/8104 @PolyGeo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it was made, but...

In the bottom right of that image there are some pencil markings and a search brings it up as part of the Norman B. Leventhal Map Center Collection from the Boston Public Library published by [Massachusetts] : Central Transportation Planning Staff.

https://collections.leventhalmap.org/search/commonwealth:7h149v32x

There are no shapefiles listed, but there is a GeoTIFF available under the Downloads section from the link above (see right side panel underneath map) and sources where you could inquire further to see if more detailed access is offered for your needs.